# TeXstudio won't download "unable to locate package textstudio"

Tags: 16.04, apt

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04lts. When I tried to install `texstudio`, an error occurred.

```
unable to locate package textstudio
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

> When I tried to install `texstudio`, an error occurred. `unable to locate package textstudio`

Theres no package such as `textstudio`; it seems you made a typing mistake. Run this command to install [TeXstudio](http://www.texstudio.org/)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texstudio
```

Comment: sorry it do  not work in my case

Comment: What error occured ? It should work because texstudio is on 16.04 repositories

Comment: Now im a new user so i have a lot of problem

Comment: It cannot upgrade 100%

Comment: Just run the command and wait till it done

Comment: Make sure you have enabled the `universe` repository